# error message when loading function from a shared library

Tags: c++, kdb

I am trying to load a C++ DLL into my C application. I have compiled a .so file successfully and have a function defined called getkobj.

When I try to load it, I get an error:

```
/home/Models/Code/makeKDBObj.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10makeKDBObjC1Ev
```

I have a header file:

```
#include "k.h"

class makeKDBObj
{
     public:
     makeKDBObj();

     virtual KK getkobj(KK FileName);
 };
```

and a source file:

```
#include "makeKDBObj.hpp"

extern "C" makeKDBObj* create_object()
{
    return new makeKDBObj;
}

extern "C" void destroy_object(makeKDBObj* object )
{
    delete object;
}

extern "C" makeKDBObj* getkobj()
{
   return new makeKDBObj;
}

K getkobj (K FileName)
{
    // ...
}
```

I can find the symbol in the file with `nm -gC makeKDBObj.so | grep getkobj`:

```
00000000000047a0 T getkobj(k0*)
```

Can you see anything that I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be that you didn't define `makeKDBObj` constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Is your syntax for extern "C" correct?

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#call-cpp

This seems to say that you have to declare the function extern "C", and then define it in a separate step.